# How can I calculate the perfect fixpoint of a stratified Datalog program?

Tags: datalog

What's the order of evaluation for the instructions in the Datalog program? Is the perfect fixpoint always the minimal fixpoint?

Answer (score 1):

If your program is stratified then you follow the strata in your calculation: start with the "basic facts" (EDBs) and then you proceed to IDBs that depend only on EDBs, to IDBs that depend only on IDBs that depend only on EDBs etc. The fixpoint is guaranteed to be unique.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the perfect model of a definite Datalog program coincides with its least Herbrand model (that's a proposition you can find e.g. in [1]).

Now, stratified Datalog program is a program in Datalog with negation that is stratifiable. The program is not definite but it is stratifiable and because of that it can be evaluated stratum by stratum (the way Alexander describes in his answer). It is not too difficult to see that you again arrive at the minimal fixpoint. There used to be a nice textbook about Datalog and deductive databases by prof. Andrei Voronkov.

The order of evaluation of a definite Datalog program does not matter. In the case of Datalog with negation you have to be more careful.

[1] Lloyd - Foundations of Logic Programming